# $scope.uiGrid is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to create a table using angularjs ui-grid but I keep getting told that $scope.uiGrid is undefined, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
    requestYelp.success(
    function(obj) 
    {
        console.log(obj.businesses[0].name);

        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableSorting: true,
            rowHeight:100,
            columnDefs: [
            { field: 'name' },
            { field: 'company'  },
            { field: 'image', cellTemplate:"<img width=\"50px\" ng-src=\"{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}\" lazy-src>"}
            ],

            data:[
            {name:obj.businesses[0].name,company: "Company1", image: obj.businesses[0].image_url},
            {name:obj.businesses[1].name,company:"Company2",image:obj.businesses[1].image_url},
            {name:obj.businesses[2].name,company:"Company3",image:obj.businesses[2].image_url}
            ]
        };
    }
);
}]);
```

`console.log(obj.businesses[0].name)` will put the right data to the console so it's not a problem with the obj variable. The code only breaks when it gets to gridOptions.

Comment: [The rest of the code, if needed](http://plnkr.co/edit/S88HoI08t3dJCZiDZCcj?p=preview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the exact details how the ui-grid works. But I'm guessing that the ui-grid directive immediately expects `$scope.gridOptions` to be available on the `$scope`. However, you are assigning `$scope.gridOptions` only after the **asynchronous** http request has finished loading.

You should try to provide an empty (or adequately primed) `$scope.gridOptions` immediately before doing the http request.

Alternatively there's a trick to delay linking of **any** directive by adding an additional `ng-if` on the same element. Set it up something like this:

`ng-if='whenHttpRequestHasFinishedLoading'`

And inside the `success()` function just set `$scope.whenHttpRequestHasFinishedLoading = true`

Answer (score 3):

I know this doesn't answer the OP's question, but this is the first hit from Google, when you search for "ui-grid $scope.uiGrid undefined".

I felt like a complete idiot when I figured out what I'd missed, but in case anyone else runs into the same issue, make sure your ui-grid directive value...

```
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions"></div>
```

...matches the name of your options object:

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {};
```